# Java Serialized Class Saved To File - How can i ensure backwards compatibility?

Tags: java, serialization, serialversionuid

I have written an Android App for producing and saving 'Photography Services' Contracts to the device as a file for later printing. The class is pretty much made up of integers, doubles and Strings (including base64_encoded signatures).

The class implements serialisable. However, I am worried about I update the app, forget not to edit the class & edit it, reload onto my device and have X number of contracts saved to a file and then not be able to retrieve them.

Earlier I was browsing and found serialVersionUID. In a post I read that simply by implementing this simple long value, if i update the class it will still be able to be read. Is this correct? I read the java documentation for Serializable and couldnt make much of a decision on what the result of implementing serialVersionUID is.

Can anyone help shed some light on this for me?
Just a simple yes this will work or no this wont work is sufficient and any links to help me learn will be even better!

Comment: Short answer: You can't. That's not how serialization works in Java (or really what it was meant for). You probably want to use JSON or some other serialization scheme/library that is more dynamic and forgiving.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6374646/1065197

Comment: Use another mechanism, if backwards compatibility is absolutely critical.

Comment: Short answer, you *can,* but you need to read the Versioning chapter of the Object Serialization Specification very carefully indeed, and stay within those boundaries with your changes.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain backward compatibility with serialization, you have to

1. Have the same serialVersionUID for the class you want to serialize throughout your versions.
2. You can add/remove class **methods** as you like and it won't affect serialization.
3. You can add as many new **members** as you like, and they will have the default value of their type right after the user updates the application to a new version.

Example:

```
// Old format
class FileFormat implements Serializable {
   static final long serialVersionUID = 44L;

   public String member1;
}

...
// New format
class FileFormat implements Serializable {
   static final long serialVersionUID = 44L;

   public String member1;
   public int member2;
}
```

In the above, the first time the user will read a file serialized with old FileFormat with the new application, s/he will obtain a new format FileFormat object with member2 set to 0.  (Strings/Objects will be null, floats will be 0.0f, doubles 0.0, etc.).

1. You **cannot** delete any field from the class (you will lose backward-compatibility)
2. You **cannot** change the class' hierarchy in the means of moving the class up or down

There are many other restrictions, check out the official document:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html